# Инкремент std::atomic с контролем переполнения

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Потребовалось реализовать потоково и переполнительно безопасный счетчик на `std::atomic`. Сделал вот так, как и многие в интернете:

```
template<typename T, T COUNT_MIN = std::numeric_limits<T>::min()
                   , T COUNT_MAX = std::numeric_limits<T>::max() >
T SafeIncrement(std::atomic<T> & counter)
{
   static_assert(MIN < MAX, "range wrong");

   T current = counter.load();
   T result  = current == COUNT_MAX  ? COUNT_MIN  : current + 1;
   while(!counter.compare_exchange_strong(current, result))
   {
       result = current == COUNT_MAX ? COUNT_MIN : current + 1;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Но у меня возникло подозрение, не возникнет ли здесь гонок. При интенсивном почти непрерывном вызове `SafeIncrement` из параллельных потоков, не возможна ли ситуация когда отдельные потоки будут вечно (или надолго!) промахиваться с обменом пусть и атомарном?

Поясню о чем речь. Гонка была бы невозможна если бы потоки выполняли обмен строго экслюзивно и по-очередеи. Например, если они исполняются псевдопараллельно на одном вычислителе или такой механиз обеспечивает ОС. У нас же гарантируется только экслюзивность, а не очередность.

Так вот, на эту тему что-то предусмотрено в реализациях `std::atomic`? Или есть правильные решения?

Comment: *при использовании алгоритмов основанных на CAS-цикле лучше использовать оператор do...while вместо простого while*

Comment: при интенсивном использовании просядет производительность, т.к. большинству потоков потребуется несколько итераций. В яве для таких счетчиков есть класс `LongAdder`, в котором поток, который не смог записать свою сумму в счетчик, создает новую ячейку в массиве и накапливает сумму в ней.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такая ситуация невозможна. Потому что каждая ошибка обмена означает что какой-то другой поток успешно этот самый обмен совершил. Таким образом, на каждой итерации цикла уменьшается число конкурирующих потоков - а значит, рано или поздно они закончатся (если только по какой-то причине не прибывают быстрее чем убывают).

Однако, значительное замедление при одновременном доступе из разных потоков действительно возможно, поэтому таких переменных стоит избегать.

PS Ваше решение мне кажется каким-то переусложненным: можно же просто использовать беззнаковые целочисленные типы, у них переполнение не вызывает UB.

Comment: Ну, формально возможно, что один поток будет постоянно успешно совершать обмены, а второй постоянно промахиваться, разве нет?

Comment: @VladD квант времени слишком большой для того чтобы так случилось. А ядра у процессора симметричны, отсюда тоже не может такая фигня вылезти...

Comment: @VladD разве что на NUMA-архитектуре такое будет возможно, но это надо тоже постараться еще написать программу которая не будет делать ничего кроме инкрементов...

Comment: Ну, это мы уже из свойств языка опускаемся к особенностям конкретных архитектур...

Comment: @PavelMayorov У вас объяснение невозможности не корректное, причем тут что другой успел обменять.

Comment: @Cerbo как при чем? Если он успел обменять - значит, на следующем шаге у нас минус один конкурент.

Comment: уточнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Cerbo не вижу принципиальных изменений